# PHPStorm 8 paste

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Whenever I try to paste something in PHPStorm 8 IDE, it pastes the same content multiple times (sometimes more than 10 times). 
This is really driving me nuts, is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me.

Comment: Try the latest version: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program